# No matching function - ifstream open()

Tags: c++, string, iostream

This is the part of the code with an error:

```
std::vector<int> loadNumbersFromFile(std::string name)
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(name); // the error is here
    if(!file) {
        std::cout << "\nError\n\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int current;
    while(file >> current) {
        numbers.push_back(current);
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

And well, I kind of have no idea what is going on. The whole thing compiles properly in VS. However I need to compile this with dev cpp.

I commented out the line throwing errors in the code above. The errors are:

```
no matching function for call 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)
no matching function for call 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)
```

---

In different parts of code I get errors like `numeric_limits is not a member of std`, or `max() has not been declared`, although they exist in `iostream` class and everything works in VS.

---

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you have proper includes? Got your include <fstream> and include <string>?

Comment: Don't be offended, that's commonly the exact reason :)

Comment: I'm not, I would ask that myself ;d

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Change to:

```
file.open(name.c_str());
```

or just use the constructor as there is no reason to separate construction and open:

```
std::ifstream file(name.c_str());
```

Support for [`std::string` argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) was added in c++11.

As `loadNumbersFromFile()` does not modify its argument pass by `std::string const&` to document that fact and avoid unnecessary copy.