# Downgrading from C++11 part of code

Tags: c++

Specifically:

```
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

It throws the following errors:

1. Numeric_limits is not part of std
2. Expected primary-expressions before '<' token
3. No matching function for call to max()

It works in VS, but doesn't in Dev cpp.

How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Have you included `<limits>`?

Comment: Just to note I never said the `numeric_limits` was a c++11 issue in your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552753/no-matching-function-ifstream-open/16552779#16552779). I missed this error in your question, and only commented on the use of `ifstream`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a problem with C++03/C++11, but the lack of an include:

```
#include <limits>
```

The template `std::numeric_limits<>` exists for a long time already.

Comment: +1. And the reason it works in MSVC is because a large portion of the standard headers end up included indirectly by coincidence (`<vector>` pulls in tons of other headers, for example)

Comment: Yes, the standard does not require any indirect inclusion or require that indirect inclusions should not happen within the standard library headers. If you want to have portable code you need to make sure that you include everything that you need.

Comment: I hear they changed `<algorithm>` to not include `<iterator>`. Good fight to any code that was depending on that :p

Comment: @chris: Who included `iterator` inside `algorithm`? I have been including both in gcc forever :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I think STL mentioned that MSVC made that change in either his STL series or Core C++ series. It's not really recent or anything if it's from the STL series.