# Open every file of the vector array, count the number of lines in each file using lineCount function

Tags: c++

I need to open a specified directory entered by user, open every files of that folder directory, count the number of line of each file and then finally to do a total sum of all the lines of all files in that folder. So basically I succeed to open the directory and put all the file names in a vector array. So I did:

```
vector < string > dirlist;

dirlist.push_back(ent->d_name) //To add file names in the vector array
```

The names was successfully push in the vector array and I was able to display it.

But now I want to use a for_each to apply `lineCount` function to each element of the vector array I can’t:

```
for_each (dirlist.begin(),dirlist.end(), lineCount);
```

lineCount function:

```
void lineCount (string fn)
{ 
    ifstream fileInput;
    string line;
    int number_of_lines = 0;  //initialise number_of_lines to 0
    fileInput.open(fn.c_str(), std::fstream::in); //open file
    if(fileInput.is_open()) {  //test if file is opened
            while(getline(fileInput, line)) {
                ++number_of_lines;
            }
            cout << "Number of lines in file: " << number_of_lines;
            fileInput.close();
    }
    else cout <<"Unable to Open File"<<endl;

}
```

Now I get Unable to open for every files in the directory

Comment: What do you need this for? You can achieve this using your favourite unix shell.

Comment: @Melebius It is for an project using CodeBlocks.

Comment: Since you're only reading from the file, you don't need to use `| std::fstream::out` - and in fact if you do, you make get a privilege error.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't"?

Comment: @John Burger..I removed it. I get error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&, const openmode&)'

Comment: We don't know what your problem is: Does it give a compiler error? Does it give one of your error messages? Does it simply do nothing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No matching function - ifstream open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552753/no-matching-function-ifstream-open)

Comment: @Melpomene I meant to say that I want to use a for_each to apply lineCount function to each element of the dirlist vector array but I can’t.

Comment: @ASG What do you mean by "I can't"?

Comment: @Melpomene I can`t apply lineCount function to each element of the vector array

Comment: @ASG What do you mean by "I can't"?

Comment: @ASG What happens when you try? **You** can't, but you're asking the computer to. What is the computer telling you to say that it cannot?

Comment: @Melpomene thanks for the post it fixed that part but now I can`t open each file and the else part is executed for each element of the vector array. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
fileInput.open(fn, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out); //open file
```

has two problems:

1. The first parameter to `open()` expects a `const char *` - you're giving it a `string`.
   Use `fn.c_str()`
2. The second parameter says to open the file for *both* `in` and `out` - but you're only going to be reading it.
   Remove `| std::fstream::out`.

And don't forget: all that you are passing to the `lineCount()` function is the name of the file: the actual directory still needs to be prepended to the name of the file. I don't know what you call it - or if the directory has a path separator (`'\'` or `'/'`) at the end of it - but you basically need to do this:

```
fn = dir + fn;
```

before attempting to open the file.

Comment: ...Thank you very much. It worked but the problem now it that the else statement is executed...I don`t get the number of files but I get "The File Name" Unable to Open File when it should open the file, count the line number then display it.

Comment: I get Unable to open files for every files in the folder

Comment: @ASG I've updated my answer: please have a look. You really need to use a debugger, and look at the values that are being used. This should help you understand what is actually happening