# Why cannot I initialize a ifstream ref from constructor?

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize the std::ifstream ref from constructor but I get an error saying

```
invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ifstream& {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
  A(const std::string& file_name):inFile(file_name){}
```

Below is the code

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class A{
  public:
    A(const std::string& file_name):inFile(file_name){}

  private:
    std::ifstream& inFile;
};

int main(){
  A("text.txt");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No matching function - ifstream open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552753/no-matching-function-ifstream-open)
You need to feed a c-style string into inFile, or use `.c_str()`

Comment: @Helium_1s2 That is not it.  The OP is trying to initialize a `std::ifstream&` with a `std::string`.

Comment: `inFile` is a reference to a `std::ifstream`, not an `std::ifstream`. And `std::string` is certainly not an `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Remove the `&` from `std::ifstream& inFile;`

Comment: @NathanOliver My intention was to place &. Because similar with in type and it works (replaced std::ifstream with int)

Comment: @mato Then `A(const std::string& file_name)` needs to be `A(std::ifstream& file_stream)`

Comment: And make dang sure that the lifetime of the `ifstream` you provide exceeds that of the `A` instance.

Comment: And when you initialize the `std::ifstream`, make sure to use a `const char *`, call it on `myString.c_str()`, or compile using c++11.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a *ref* `&`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Problem

In

```
class A{
public:
 A(const std::string& file_name):inFile(file_name){}

private:
 std::ifstream& inFile;
};
```

`inFile` must be initialized to reference an existing `istream`. `inFile(file_name)` does not construct an `istream`; it attempts to make `inFile` refer to a `string`. The compiler can't make that work and emits an error.

**Explanation of above**

`inFile` is not a `ifstream`. [It is a reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references), an alias, to a variable that is an `ifstream`. You cannot construct a reference because there isn't anything there to construct. It's just a new name for a variable that already exists. The referenced variable must be constructed instead.

**Why this worked with an `int`**

If you

```
class A{
  public:
    A(int & an_Int):int_Ref(an_Int){}

  private:
    int & int_Ref;
};
```

`int_Ref` refers to the `int` that `an_Int` refers to. If instead you

```
A(int an_int):int_Ref(an_int){}
```

it will still compile, but you have a problem because `int_Ref` refers to `an_int`, an automatic variable scoped to the constructor. `an_int` is dead and possibly buried by the time you get to use the `A` for anything. Using `int_Ref` would be [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and since the behaviour is undefined anything can happen including the behaviour you expect. This can fool you for a good long time before a grasshopper sneezes and the program suddenly stops working correctly. In truth it *never* worked correctly.

```
A(const std::string& file_name):intRef(file_name){}
```

Will not work for the same reason as above an `int` reference cannot refer to a `std::string`.

## Solution

There are two reasonable options:

**Option 1**

```
class A{
public:
 A(const std::string& file_name):inFile(file_name){}

private:
 std::ifstream inFile; // no longer a reference
};
```

which will construct an `istream` for the named file within the instance of `A`.

**Option 2**

```
class A{
public:
 A(std::ifstream & in):inFile(in){} // accepts ifstream reference, not string reference

private:
 std::ifstream & inFile; 
};
```

which initializes `inFile` to refer to the given pre-existing `ifstream` referred to by `in`. This means that

```
int main(){
  A("text.txt");

}
```

must become

```
int main(){
  std::ifstream in("text.txt");
  A(in);

}
```

This comes with the caveat that the `ifstream` provided to `A` must have a lifespan greater than that of the instance of `A`. That means

```
A ABuilder(const std::string& file_name)
{
    std::ifstream in(file_name);
    return A(in);
}
```

is a deathtrap. The returned `A` contains a reference to an object that no longer exists.

Because of the increased chance of error with option 2, I recommend preferring option 1

Comment: In the problem part of you explanation you say `inFile(file_name) does not construct an istream`. Do you know why? Because if I do the same for int value it works for some reason. Is it because of `std::ifstream`'s lack of copy constructor?

Comment: @mato couldn't answer in a comment. Edited question.

Comment: Thank you for lucid clarification.