# build error "no matching function for call to ‘sg_ofstream::open(const wchar_t*, std::ios_base::openmode&)"

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to build Jsbsim under cygwin64 platform by following instructions [here](https://jsbsim-team.github.io/jsbsim-reference-manual/mypages/quickstart-building-the-program/).

But I got error:

```
$ cmake ..
$ make
[ 1%] Building CXX object src/simgear/io/iostreams/CMakeFiles/IOStreams.dir/sgstream.cxx.o
/home/Igor/jsbsim/src/simgear/io/iostreams/sgstream.cxx: In constructor ‘sg_ifstream::sg_ifstream(const SGPath&, std::ios_base::openmode)’:
/home/Igor/jsbsim/src/simgear/io/iostreams/sgstream.cxx:39:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘sg_ifstream::open(const wchar_t*, std::ios_base::openmode&)’
```

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? This issue reminds me of other `no matching function for call to ‘ifstream::open` posts raised on this site: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552753/no-matching-function-ifstream-open)

Comment: I use the latest version: gcc 7.4.0