# No matching function for call when reading file

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to open my file and perform a read operation on my second file. I'm not sure what went wrong.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::string&)’
     file.open(filename);
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedBag<string> dictionary;
    fstream file;
    string word;
    file.open("dictionary.txt", ios::in); // open a file to perform read operation using file object
    if (file.is_open()) // check whether file is open
    {
        while (file >> word)
        {
            dictionary.add(word);
        }
    }

    string filename;
    string words;
    cout << "Enter the name of the file that contains words to check:" << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    file.open(filename);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (file >> words)
        {
            if (!dictionary.contains(words))
            {
                cout << "The following words in the file " << filename << " are not spelled correctly:" << endl;
                cout << words << endl;
                cout << "Thanks for using the spell checker system." << endl; 
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Not that this seems directly related to your problem, but it doesn't look like you close `dictionary.txt` before opening `filename`. That's going to fail.

Comment: Looks like your compiler is compiling to an older Standard. The `std::string` overload for `open` was added in C++11, [the 2011 Standard Revision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history). This could be a simple fix, adding the appropriate compiler option to request at least C++11 support. Otherwise you need to get a newer compiler.

Comment: If you add your compiler and compiler version to the question, we can offer better help and probably tell you exactly what you need to do to enable a more recent Standard. If you are using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) you should add that as well.

Comment: Could you have reduced your [mre] to something more like `int main()
{
    fstream file;    string filename = "filename";
    file.open(filename); 
}` and still get the same error when compiling? (Your example code does not need to do anything useful other than reproduce the error.)

Comment: This question covers an alternative should you be unable to change the Standard revision  or compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552753/no-matching-function-ifstream-open

Comment: Side note: [mre] is something you'll be asked for a lot around here. There are many reasons for that, the most important, to me at any rate, are including a MRE makes the question more accessible to future askers with a similar problem and MRE is a powerful debugging technique that almost always leads to an asker finding and fixing the problem themselves with no question asked. The latter may not have helped much here since there is nothing wrong with your code; you needed to know that your tools are out of date.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory.  `open()` in the version of C++ you are compiling for does not accept a `std::string` as a parameter. That overload was added in C++11.

So, either update your project to compile for C++11 or later, or else for older versions you will have to use this instead:

```cpp
file.open(filename.c_str());
```